# Date does not alert in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript

```
var dateNum = Number('/Date(1306348200000)/'.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(dateNum.substr(6)));   
alert(formattedDate);
```

What's wrong with this code? Why does it not execute and give me the desired result...

Comment: Why don't you debug a bit on your own? If I copy this in the console, then I get a `Type Error`. More specifically, in the second line and even more specifically for `dateNum.substr(6)`. Why? because `dateNum` is not a string. It's a number. At one point you should start reading documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(dateNum.toString().substr(6)));
```

Felix's comment is the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea why you're doing it in a complicated way - `/ /` is for regular expressions, not for dates. Then you also have this notation inside a string. I'm not aware of any `/Date(...)/` format. What you're doing on the first line is parsing the number out of it, but why not do it yourself?

This works fine:

```
var formattedDate = new Date(1306348200000);   
alert(formattedDate);
```

To format it, you would need certain functions to combine the date components as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2

Comment: Even shorter: `alert(new Date(1306348200000));`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting function you have here. I see at least one problem `dateNum` is not a string.

Might be a good idea to submit what you expect to get from your code.

Comment: `substr` is actually a valid method... for strings.